# rbind and cbind commands equivalent in SPSS

Tags: r, spss

can someone provide and equivalent code in SPSS that merges datasets in SPSS to replicate the rbind and cbind commands usable in R ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add *rows* from `dataset1` to `dataset2`, you can use [ADD FILES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_25.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_add_files.html). This requires that both datasets hold the same variables, with matching variable names and formats.

To add *columns* from `dataset1` to `dataset2`, use [MATCH FILES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_25.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_match_files.html#syn_match_files). This command matches the values for the desired variables in `dataset2` to the right rows in `dataset1` using keys present in both files (such as a respondent id). The keys are defined in the `BY` subcommand.

Please note that R and SPSS work in a totally different way. In short, SPSS (mainly) works with datasets in which variables are defined and formatted, while R can handle single values, vectors, matrices, dataframes etc. Simply copying columns from an existing dataset to another dataset (without paying attention tohow the files are sorted) and  simply adding rows without matching the variable names and types in the existing dataset are very unusual in SPSS.

If you post an example of what you are trying to achieve, I could give you a more useful answer...